# Are $L^p$ spaces inclusion continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. We know that if $p \leq q$, then 
$$
  L^q(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu) \subseteq L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu).
$$
My question: is the inclusion
$$
   \iota : (L^q, ||\cdot||_q) \hookrightarrow (L^p, ||\cdot ||_p)
$$
continuous for arbitrary $p \leq q$? If not, what if we suppose $p$ and $q$ are Hölder conjugate?

Comment: By Hölder's inequality for $f\in L^q$ you have$$\|f\|_p\le\mu(\Omega)^{\frac 1 p- \frac 1 q}\|f\|_q.$$